# Call to /signalr/negotiate always return null

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, signalr

I found some sample code of a basic signalr application.  I created a new ASP.NET MVC 4 project and plopped the code in.  It worked perfectly.  I then went to add the exact same code into the real project I was working on.  Unfortunately, the negotiate call always returns null... It returns a success, but no JSON is returned...  I've tried removing all other JS, I've tried removing all my routes (signalr is the first line in Application_Start already), I've tried creating a new controller and View that has no reference to _Layout and added the JS manually... It still doesn't return anything.  I also tried deploying the code to IIS, but no luck there, either...

Does anyone have any ideas?  Thanks!

Edit: I'm using signalr 1.1.2.

Edit2: I don't think this is an issue, but the project must run in 64-bit.

Comment: Does the response to /signalr/negotiate give a 200 status?

Comment: Yeah, it does.  That is the weird part.  Looking at it it with Fiddler, it gives back no JSON, but a 200 status.

Comment: Does /signalr/hubs give you the normal JS? Have you tried looking at the JS log output? http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/hubs-api/hubs-api-guide-javascript-client#logging

Comment: It sounds like something else is stealing that route. Is the route registered first? Does your app have anything that messes with the response?

Comment: Yes, /signalr/hubs returns normal JS.  I tried removing all my custom routing and it still didn't work.  I took out all custom JS and just made a blank page and it still didn't work.  We mess with the response only when exceptions get thrown, which in this case does not happen.

Comment: Yes, I registered the signalR route first.

Comment: Make sure you do not have ",IsolateApps" at the end of each key hex value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, this was an odd issue.  I turned on a bunch of logging for SignalR and nothing came up, so I put a breakpoint in the Application_Error method.  It turns out that we had defined a machineKey element in the web.config file.  The validation attribute that was defined was not a "valid" one per .NET 4.5.  This caused the entire issue.